# JFreechart with table below it

Tags: jfreechart

I would like to generate a main window that has a xy graph on top with a table below.  Eventually, the xy plot should show points representing cities to visit, solid black lines representing barriers that can't be crossed.  And then the program will try to find the shortest path.

In the table, let the table have 6 columns with headers "index", "2", "4", "8", "16", and "32".  The rows contain data line 1, "20.5 / 220", "30.2 / 350", ... where the first value is an reference index, and the other values are a string where the first number represents the length of the path and the second number represents the time it took to calculate.  The column represent the number of threads to run simultaneously.

But for now, I just want to plot an XY graph on top and a table on bottom.

Answer (score 1):

`CrosshairDemo1` and `CrosshairDemo2` are good [examples](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) of how to do this.